Using Sequelize bulkCreate as a bulk update
We have a node project with Sequelize and postgresql, and I need to improve the performance of some endpoints. And there are several cases in the code where an update query is made for each row (with different data for each row), and this becomes a problem even with like 50 rows. So, I'm trying to implement something like a bulk update.
The bulkCreate method of Sequelize.Model has the option updateOnDuplicate, so, if you only pass rows that already exist, you can actually use it as a "bulk update", and it's much faster that doing an update for each row. For example:
await models.Shipping.bulkCreate(
  shippings,
  {
    fields: ['packageId', 'labelUrl', 'custom'],
    updateOnDuplicate: ['label_url', 'custom']
  }
)

Where shippings is an array containing row data. This will update the fields label_url and custom for each one of those rows in the database.
But apparently you can only do this if you pass all necessary row data to bulkCreate. If you pass only the data you want to update, like this:
shippings = [{
  labelUrl: 'example.com',
  custom: 'test
}]

It won't work if you have NOT NULL constraints on other columns, because that column is not present in the "insert" data.
Is there a clean way to bypass this? Or maybe another way to make a fast update for several rows with different data?

I don't think what you want is natively supported in Sequelize - as you noticed the bulkCreate needs all the non nullable values because it will actually create missing rows, and update existing ones.
Alternatives:

There is a model.update(values, {where:}) method but this would implies setting the same values for all your target rows, which might not be what you want.

You could do a multiple updates in parallel (using a transaction if needed):


await Promise.all(shippings.map(elt => 
  models.Shipping.update(elt, { where: { id: elt.id }, transaction }
)


If really you want a single query, then you could probably write a custom raw query, using a generated CASE block for each of your shipping item, but I'm not sure it would be more efficient, the query could be heavy.

